# Raise events in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, timer

I am trying to write program that saves data every few minutes. Not as and when a request comes in. For that I need to use an application variable to capture the number of occurances and every 5 minutes I clear the queue and write persist the numbers to database. 
1. Is that a good idea?
2. Does it impact performance?

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Try to narrow it in a bit or you'll get broad answer such as, _Any approach you can get to work that meets your needs is a good idea_.

Comment: Since `Not as and when a request comes in`, why don't you try a windows service running in the background?